# Is there a website for academic computer science jobs in the US like mathjobs.org?

Tags: job, job-search, postdocs, computer-science

I know there is a mathjobs website in the US called mathjobs.org, which is the main website for posting math jobs in the US universities. But is there a similar one for the computer science jobs? I'm asking because I searched for csjobs.org and computersciencejobs.org, but I couldn't find a relevant match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're open to adjacent fields, you also have http://www.bioinformatics.org/jobs/ .

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm actually trained in mathematics wanting to switch t some interdisciplinary areas.

Comment: There's some hardcore math work in bioinformatics, look into networks and modelling. Can't give you more pointers than that, I'm the bio guy the math people collaborate with :).

Comment: There is this web site https://academicjobsonline.org/ajo (which is built on the same platform as mathjobs.org), but only a few universities use it.

Comment: Terdon: Sure, I'm a differential geometer/complex analyst/Riemann surface theoristwith basic backgrounds in algebraic topology etc. wanting to work in somewhat applied areas like medical imaging, shape analysis etc., but I guess if bioinformatics use pure mathematics related ot my backgrounds, I'd love to know what are those areas and who study them. I'd await your follow up comment :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best source for CS jobs in the US is the [Computing Research Association (CRA)](http://cra.org/). They maintain a [jobs site](http://cra.org/ads/) that AFAIK most departments post to.